# Replace text in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a table with beautifulSoup and remove the blank spaces found in some rows with - so instead of

```
<tr>
<td><small>15</small></td>
<td><small><small>Cat</small></small></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><small><small>   </small></small></td>
<td><small><small> </small></small></td>
</tr>
```

I want

```
<tr>
<td><small>15</small></td>
<td><small><small>Cat</small></small></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><small><small>-</small></small></td>
<td><small><small>-</small></small></td>
</tr>
```

I have kind of managed to do this with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("table.html"))

for a in soup.findAll('small'):
    a.replaceWith("-")
```

That does remove the space, but it also removes the text 15 and cat (I know what I have replaces everything in the  tag). That is as far as I have been able to get. How can I fix that code so it will only replace the space with -?

EDIT: Sorry here is the raw code

```
<tr>
<td><small>15</small></td >
<td><small><small>&nbsp;</small></small></td >
</tr>
<tr>
<td><small><small>&nbsp; &nbsp;</small></small></td >
<td><small><small>&nbsp;</small></small></td >
</tr>
```

Comment: check it before replacing: if a.isspace(): a.replaceWith("-")

Comment: That comes back with
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: I'm so sorry, please check my answer that I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(open("table.html"))
for i in soup.findAll('small'):
    if i.text == "" or "&nbsp;" in i.text:
        i.string = '-'
print soup
```

you need to check the value before replacing.

Comment: That didn't work for me so I copied the space that is in the file and I get `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file but no encoding declated` So I added `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` and now I get `UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if i.text == "┬á":`

Comment: @Howlin that error refers to the unicode. have a look into: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: @Howlin please update your post with your code that I can test it.

Comment: I have tried all the different encodings on that link. The code is in the first post already. (the first lot of <tr>)

Comment: @Howlin I tested this code with your data , it works fine. update your post with real sample data that I can find your problem.

Comment: Sorry I was pasting the wrong code in first, I have added it now.

Comment: Sorry still not working. Here is a picture of what I have and what I see when I try run that. http://i.imgur.com/bMne7uj.png

Comment: @Howlin so It works fine but it changes &nbsp; to another thing in your system. but in my system it changes to '-'. so please upgrade your BeautifulSoup lib for making ensure. and test your '-' with str('-').

Comment: That worked, I had beautifulsoup 4 installed, I installed beautifulsoup 3 and it works now...thanks :D